# Xcode - error building Framework

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, libtool-xcode

I am following [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/65964/create-a-framework-for-ios) tutorial to wrap my static library in a framework. The problem appears at the very last phase - running script in "Aggregate" target. I am getting an error:

`libtool: can't locate file for: -lPods-MyLib`

The script looks like this:

```
set -e

# If we're already inside this script then die
if [ -n "$RW_MULTIPLATFORM_BUILD_IN_PROGRESS" ]; then
exit 0
fi
export RW_MULTIPLATFORM_BUILD_IN_PROGRESS=1

RW_FRAMEWORK_NAME=${PROJECT_NAME}
RW_INPUT_STATIC_LIB="lib${PROJECT_NAME}.a"
RW_FRAMEWORK_LOCATION="${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${RW_FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework"

function build_static_library {
    # Will rebuild the static library as specified
    #     build_static_library sdk
    xcrun xcodebuild -project "${PROJECT_FILE_PATH}" \
    -target "${TARGET_NAME}" \
    -configuration "${CONFIGURATION}" \
    -sdk "${1}" \
    ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO \
    BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" \
    OBJROOT="${OBJROOT}" \
    BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}" \
    SYMROOT="${SYMROOT}" $ACTION
}

function make_fat_library {
    # Will smash 2 static libs together
    #     make_fat_library in1 in2 out
    xcrun lipo -create "${1}" "${2}" -output "${3}"
}

# 1 - Extract the platform (iphoneos/iphonesimulator) from the SDK name
if [[ "$SDK_NAME" =~ ([A-Za-z]+) ]]; then
RW_SDK_PLATFORM=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
else
echo "Could not find platform name from SDK_NAME: $SDK_NAME"
exit 1
fi

# 2 - Extract the version from the SDK
if [[ "$SDK_NAME" =~ ([0-9]+.*$) ]]; then
RW_SDK_VERSION=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
else
echo "Could not find sdk version from SDK_NAME: $SDK_NAME"
exit 1
fi

# 3 - Determine the other platform
if [ "$RW_SDK_PLATFORM" == "iphoneos" ]; then
RW_OTHER_PLATFORM=iphonesimulator
else
RW_OTHER_PLATFORM=iphoneos
fi

# 4 - Find the build directory
if [[ "$BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR" =~ (.*)$RW_SDK_PLATFORM$ ]]; then
RW_OTHER_BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${RW_OTHER_PLATFORM}"
else
echo "Could not find other platform build directory."
exit 1
fi

# Build the other platform.
build_static_library "${RW_OTHER_PLATFORM}${RW_SDK_VERSION}"

# If we're currently building for iphonesimulator, then need to rebuild
#   to ensure that we get both i386 and x86_64
if [ "$RW_SDK_PLATFORM" == "iphonesimulator" ]; then
build_static_library "${SDK_NAME}"
fi

# Join the 2 static libs into 1 and push into the .framework
make_fat_library "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${RW_INPUT_STATIC_LIB}" \
"${RW_OTHER_BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${RW_INPUT_STATIC_LIB}" \
"${RW_FRAMEWORK_LOCATION}/Versions/A/${RW_FRAMEWORK_NAME}"

# Ensure that the framework is present in both platform's build directories
cp -a "${RW_FRAMEWORK_LOCATION}/Versions/A/${RW_FRAMEWORK_NAME}" \
"${RW_OTHER_BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${RW_FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework/Versions/A/${RW_FRAMEWORK_NAME}"

# Copy the framework to the user's desktop
ditto "${RW_FRAMEWORK_LOCATION}" "${HOME}/Desktop/${RW_FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework"
```

Building static library works, building a framework works (an empty one), it just fails at running the script in "Aggregate" target. Now I noticed that in the tutorial, the author does not use Cocoapods and I do. How to fix the script?

Comment: One of the answers I found was to add `$(inherited)` to **Other Linker Flags** in **Build Settings** for Aggregate target, but that doesn't help

Comment: Why there's `pods` involved in your framework build? Do you use cocoapods in your library project?

Comment: Yes, I use Cocoapods in my static library

Comment: I dont think its correct way to add dependency to static lib pj, i will add my answer below for u

Comment: Since you are using pods, shouldn't you have a `-workspace YourProject.xcworkspace` argument in the `xcodebuild` function? Also make sure all your configurations have the Pod setup alright in Project Info.

Comment: @lostInTransit can you elaborate?

Comment: If I remember this right (from continuous integration setup), when running xcodebuild for a project with cocoapods, we need to specify the `-workspace MyProject.xcworkspace` argument. I'll be honest, that was a couple of years back, so I might be mistaken. Unfortunately I haven't done this for a fat framework before, so I might be wrong

Comment: Trying that results in an error **codebuild: error: You cannot specify targets with a workspace.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was with that part of the script:

```
function build_static_library {
    # Will rebuild the static library as specified
    #     build_static_library sdk
    xcrun xcodebuild -project "${PROJECT_FILE_PATH}" \
    -target "${TARGET_NAME}" \
    -configuration "${CONFIGURATION}" \
    -sdk "${1}" \
    ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO \
    BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" \
    OBJROOT="${OBJROOT}" \
    BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}" \
    SYMROOT="${SYMROOT}" $ACTION
}
```

Changing it to

```
function build_static_library {
    # Will rebuild the static library as specified
    #     build_static_library sdk
    xcrun xcodebuild -workspace "MyWorkspace.xcworkspace" \
    -scheme MyScheme \
    -configuration "${CONFIGURATION}" \
    -sdk "${1}" \
    ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO \
    BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" \
    OBJROOT="${OBJROOT}" \
    BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}" \
    SYMROOT="${SYMROOT}" $ACTION
}
```

Makes the framework build properly